# Usage of indexOf() to return an array in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, for-loop

So for example, i have an JSON like this:

```
     "result": [
        {
          "Id": 45,
          "data": {
            "sM": 1667,
            "Data": [
              {
                "date": "2016-02-10",
                "value": 96.0
              },
              {
                "date": "2016-02-11",
                "value": 81.0
              },
              {
                "date": "2016-02-12",
                "value": 19.0
              },
              {
                "date": "2016-02-13",
                "value": 72.0
                  },
               },

  "Id": 74,
  "data": {
    "sNe": 1434,
    "Data": [
      {
        "date": "2016-02-10",
        "value": 59.0
      },
      {
        "date": "2016-02-11",
        "value": 18.0
      },
      {
        "date": "2016-02-12",
        "value": 3.0
      }
              ]
```

And i want the "value" return in an array form like [[96,81,19,72],[59,18,3]], how may i do it?

i tried to do something like

```
     var dashboardDate= data.result; 
for (var i=0; i < dashboardData.length; i++){
                        mentionArr.push(dashboardData[i].data.mentionData);
                     }
```

But this return with date which is not doing the job.
I tired to use the indexOf() method like . indexOf("value") as well, but it doesn't seem like working.

Comment: The JSON is **invalid**. Add correct and complete JSON object.

Comment: next time, please review your question, so people can understand, simulate, and can answer you fast and easy.

Comment: i am sorry, will take care about my questions next time, was bit rush to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2-level nested loop for that. First is loop on the `result` then loop on the `Data` on each result's object. Something like this:

```
data =  JSON.parse('{"result":[{"Id":45,"data":{"sM":1667,"Data":[{"date":"2016-02-10","value":96.0},{"date":"2016-02-11","value":81.0},{"date":"2016-02-12","value":19.0},{"date":"2016-02-13","value":72.0}]}},{"Id":74,"data":{"sNe":1434,"Data":[{"date":"2016-02-10","value":59.0},{"date":"2016-02-11","value":18.0},{"date":"2016-02-12","value":3.0}]}}]}');


var dashboardData= data.result; 
var newArr = Array();
// loop against result array
for (var i=0; i < dashboardData.length; i++){
    var a = Array();
    // loop against the Data array on each object in result
    for (var x=0; x < dashboardData[i].data.Data.length; x++) {
        a.push(dashboardData[i].data.Data[x].value);
    }
    newArr.push(a);
 }
```

This will output:

```
JSON.stringify(newArr);

// outputs:
[[96,81,19,72],[59,18,3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You give this JSON,is error.

The right is

"result": [
    {
        "Id": 45,
        "data": {
            "sM": 1667,
            "Data": [
                {
                    "date": "2016-02-10",
                    "value": 96.0
                },
                {
                    "date": "2016-02-11",
                    "value": 81.0
                },
                {
                    "date": "2016-02-12",
                    "value": 19.0
                },
                {
                    "date": "2016-02-13",
                    "value": 72.0
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {

```
    "Id": 74,
    "data": {
        "sNe": 1434,
        "Data": [
            {
                "date": "2016-02-10",
                "value": 59.0
            },
            {
                "date": "2016-02-11",
                "value": 18.0
            },
            {
                "date": "2016-02-12",
                "value": 3.0
            }
        ]

    }
}
```

]

Then traverse

```
for (var i=0; i < dashboardDate.length; i++){
   dashboardDate[i].data.Data.forEach(function(item){
   mentionArr.push(item.value)
})
```

console.log(mentionArr);

Comment: This will create a 1 dimension array. The OP asked for a 2-dimension.